# SQL CLR - Does lock statement make any difference?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I have written the following piece of code ( sql clr stored procedure ) that writes messages to a local file. The problem occurs when multiple connections call the stored proc at the same time. So I used a lock statement. But this doesn't seem to make any difference? What am I doing wrong here?

```
lock (SqlContext.Pipe)
{
    StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText("C:\Date.txt");
    int y = 50;

    while (y != 0)
    {
        sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " " + serverName + " -- " + jobId.ToString() );
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(new Random().Next());
        y = y - 1;
    }
    sw.Close();

}
```

Comment: you seem to be attempting some fairly advanced code; is this really the simplest way of accomplishing what you are trying to achieve? What exactly is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: in the code provided by you no stored procedure is being called or accessed.

Comment: @HotTester, this code will be running from a SQL CLR Stored Procedure.

Comment: i missed that ! thanks for updation @astander . @Prabhu simply use the lock statement not within the sql clr sp but rather on the code in the application that is going to call it.

Comment: @HotTester, unfortunately, this might be called from within Sql Server from another SP...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

lock statement on its own doesn't protect anything.  The magic happens only when all threads lock **the same object**. In you case, each thread locks its own context pipe, the behavior is going to be identical with or without lock.

Besides, from all the damage a CLR procedure can do inside SQL, hijacking a SQL worker to wait in Sleep() is definitely a top offender. I hope you only use it for experimental purposes.

To achieve what you probably want, ie. have only one procedure execute at any time, use an application lock: [`sp_getapplock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189823.aspx). Either wrap the CLR procedure call in T-SQL `sp_getapplock`/`sp_releaseapplock`, or execute `sp_getapplock` on the context connection from your CLR code (and execute sp_releaseapplock on your way out).